# Need help understanding this perl code

Tags: regex, perl

```
$pattern = shift(@ARGV)
while(<ARGV>){
    if(/$pattern/){
        print $ARGV,": ",$_;
    }
}
```

The command: ./myprog.pl Size File*

Where File1:

```
SetSize
ResetSize
SETSIZE
resetSIZE
```

File2:

```
This is a new file
and its Size is very small.
```

The output:

```
File1: SetSize
File1: ResetSize
File2: and its Size is very small
```

Could someone please explain that main code to me. I really dont understand how there are two File print outs where each while loop is running each argument once and there is only 1 if condition. How is arg1 (File 1) outputting twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`while(<ARGV>)` is a bit of Perl magic: it will give you *lines* from each file listed in `@ARGV`. Relevant docs: [perlio: I/O Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators) and [perlvar: ARGV](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#ARGV).

Comment: So it takes each arg and reads its file till it reaches the end and then goes to the next argument?

Comment: Yes. It will open the file named by first argument and return each line; when it's done, it will open the next one. At that moment, your `ARGV` contains `"File1"` and `"File2"` due to shell glob expansion, so it will go through those two files.